# Behavior of 'Column' object within function spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writting a code to replace characters with the following pathern : [^\w | ] with '' . The point is that when use the DataFrame 'sentenceDF' within my function 'removePunctuation' i get the following error 'column' object is not callable'.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, trim, col, lower

    def removePunctuation(column):
        cleanString = column
        cleanString = cleanString.select(regexp_replace(sentenceDF['sentence'],'[^\w | ]','').alias('sentence'))
        cleanString = cleanString.select(regexp_replace(cleanString['sentence'],'_','').alias('sentence'))
        cleanString = cleanString.select(lower(cleanString['sentence']))

        return cleanString



    sentenceDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Hi, you!',),
                                             (' No under_score!',),
                                             (' *      Remove punctuation then spaces  * ',)], ['sentence'])

    result = sentenceDF.select(removePunctuation(col('sentence')))
    result.show()
```

TraceBack :

```
    TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) 
    <ipython-input-50-aa978fac8bae> in <module>() 
         15 (' * Remove punctuation then spaces * ',)], ['sentence']) 
         16 
    ---> 17 result = sentenceDF.select(removePunctuation(col('sentence')))  

         18 result.show() 

    <ipython-input-50-aa978fac8bae> in removePunctuation(column) 
         4 def removePunctuation(column): 
         5 cleanString = column 
   ----> 6 cleanString = cleanString.select(regexp_replace(sentenceDF['sentence'],'[^\w | ]','').alias('sentence')) 
         7 cleanString = cleanString.select(regexp_replace(cleanString['sentence'],'_','').alias('sentence')) 
         8 cleanString = cleanString.select(lower(cleanString['sentence'])) TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable 

    Command took 0.09 seconds -- by andres.velez.e@gmail.com at 10/30/2016, 2:48:17 PM on My Cluster (6 GB)
```

Comment: I think you just want an RDD and map operations, not a dataframe or select statements

Comment: I bet it could be done that way. The point here is that i do not understand the behavior of  my dataFrame when i pass 'col('sentence')' to my function. If you could explain me why i get 'column' object is not callable' and help me to fix it i would appreciate it.

Comment: Providing the traceback would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this - You get the same error.

```
col('sentence').select()
```

Suggestion: Always try to write the code out before you refactor to functions.

Anyways, here's what you want, I think.

```
def removePunctuation(df, column):
    cleanString = df.select(trim(lower(col('sentence'))).alias('sentence'))
    cleanString = cleanString.select(regexp_replace('sentence','[^\w]|\s+|_','').alias('sentence'))

    return cleanString

result = removePunctuation(sentenceDF, 'sentence')
result.show()

+--------------------+
|            sentence|
+--------------------+
|               hiyou|
|        nounderscore|
|removepunctuation...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. I did try the code before refactor it to a function. Actually my function works fine if i call it this way 'result = removePunctuation(sentenceDF)'